# How can I set the list index when using Super Simple View Engine

Tags: nancy

I have a view where I want to iterate a list in the model to render the view, the current code is something like

```
<form method="Post">
  <table class="table">
   @Each
     <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="Id[]" value="@Current.Id" />@Current.Id
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Name[]" value="@Current.Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Code[]" value="@Current.Code"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
   @EndEach
  </table>
</form>
```

What I actually wish to do is

```
<form method="Post">
  <table class="table">
   @Each
     <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="Id[@CurrentIndex]" value="@Current.Id" />@Current.Id
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Name[@CurrentIndex]" value="@Current.Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Code[@CurrentIndex]" value="@Current.Code"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
   @EndEach
  </table>
</form>
```

where @CurrentIndex will insert the list index.

List index can then be used to bind the property to a list during POST with something like

```
 Post["/"] = _ => {
    var list = this.Bind<List<Model>>();
    ...... do something with list .........

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSVE is "dumb", there's no way to execute any arbitrary code. The only way to do this would be to put the index into your model, you can do it with LINQ with something like (not compiled, just typed from memory):

```
var indexedModel = model.Select((m,i) => new { Index = i, Model = m });
```

Then in your view do something like:

```
<form method="Post">
  <table class="table">
   @Each
     <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="Id[@Current.Index]" value="@Current.Model.Id" />@Current.Id
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Name[@Current.Index]" value="@Current.Model.Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Code[@Current.Index]" value="@Current.Model.Code"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
   @EndEach
  </table>
</form>
```